# Add Multiple Select elements onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 div's aligned next to each other and an ADD button.Below is the html

```
<div class="_25">
    <label for="25">Mode</label>
    <select name="mode">
        <option value="0">Select One</option>
        <option value="fcl/fcl">FCL/FCL</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Onclick of ADD button, I want to append another `<select></select>` element with the same name but in an array. I have tried various method, to no avail while trying to append them.
For Eg: first select element should have `name=mode[0]`, second `mode[1]` and so on.

Comment: No there is a requirement ,where the user would want multiple drop down field for the same purpose ,say for MODE in  this case.So i need to give an 'ADD' option .

Comment: I believe the user was asking to store the names of each select (when added via the add button) in an array, not to name the original select as `mode[]`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create name attributes in that way, you can add `mode[]` name attributes to your select elements and on the server side you will have an array. However if you want to create select elements with different names you can try:

```
$('#add').click(function(e) {
    $('select').last().clone().prop('name', function(_, name){
        return name.replace(/\d+/, function(num) {
            return +num + 1;
        }); 
    }).appendTo('#hell');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vSZ79/

Comment: Where is the like button when you need it? `.appendTo('#hell')` ?!?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using inner html? One way is that have another div which can have all dynamic select elements to be appended. In javascript you can then use innerHTML and give it a style/name/id.

Answer (score 0):

Add button and change select name to `mode[]`

```
<div class="_25">
    <label for="25">Mode</label>
    <select name="mode[]">
        <option value="0">Select One</option>
        <option value="fcl/fcl">FCL/FCL</option>
   </select>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="ADD" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    var elem = $(this).closest('div').find('select:last');
    elem.clone(true).insertAfter(elem);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/FkrkH/

At server-side, your variable `mode` is an array. You can test by using `mode[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 <input type="button" onclick="add_s();" value="ADD select" />

function add_s() {
        var ttl_slcts = $('._25 select').length;
        var a = "<select name=mode[" + ttl_slcts + "] ><option>a</option>     <option>b</option></select>";
        $('._25').append(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each element with jQuery, and with a little help from a regular expression, increment the values. You also should start with mode[0] just to keep consistancy.

```
$('.add').click(function(){
   var currentName = $('select:last').attr('name'); // starting name should be mode[0]
   var pattern =  /^mode\[(\d)\]$/; 
   var newName = pattern.exec(currentName)[1];
   newName++;
   newName = "mode["+newName+"]";
   $('select').attr('name', newName).appendTo('div._25');
});
```